# How does wifi-based geolocation work?

Tags: wifi, google, geolocation

Looking at the [Google geolocation API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/geolocation/) it claims:

> Geolocation API returns a location and accuracy radius based on
>   information about cell towers and WiFi nodes that the mobile client
>   can detect.

Assuming a phone is in airplane mode or has no sim card and thus cannot connect to cell towers, and assuming that GPS is also disabled, how can a phone determine its location based off of only the wifi networks in range?

Is Google using the collected data from street view wifi MAC addresses, and combining it with the GPS from the street view van? would this correlation data be stored on the phone, or downloaded as-needed via a data connection? or does this only work with known wifi networks? is it based off of the MAC address or the wifi network name?

Is this Google-specific or are there other API's/companies that can do this (and not rely on Google as their back-end?)

Comment: Google USED to use public wifi networks that were open to determine location, but that was deemed unconstitutional.  It only determines location based off of wifi networks that you allow access.  If you're in Airplane mode, then even wifi networks are unavailable.  This link I believe answers your question: http://superuser.com/questions/727732/how-does-wifi-determine-a-devices-location

Comment: I'm not sure that this is an Info Sec question ...

Comment: @raz do you have some link of google using public networks being made unconstitutional? AFAICT its still an open issue.

Comment: I mis-spoke... kind of.  Here is a link to where the implication is that a judge did declare Google broke laws  http://www.bloomberg.com/news/2013-06-10/google-seeks-ruling-street-view-didn-t-break-wiretap-laws.html, but it was later ruled that no laws were technicall broken:  http://www.wired.com/2013/09/googles-wifi-wiretapping/

Comment: @raz - entering airplane mode will turn off wifi, but does nothing to ensure that it remains off - I simply wanted to create a situation where wifi can be active, but not cell towers. I am not sure if a wifi network needs to be open or not, can't you still see the name/strength of it? what more would you need for location purposes? or do you mean to say that it only works where one can connect to the network? (what level of connection is necessary - a captive portal? internet access?)

Comment: @user2813274 Wifi Name and BSSID (MAC address) of non-hidden SSID networks are sent unencrypted and on regular intervals to everybody around. Regardless of internet connection, captive portals or openness.
You need however an internet connection to look up where the access points are.

Comment: @user2813274  you bring up a really good point, and I did not realize that Wifi would be turned back on.  It's weird that for as long as I've used and developed for Android I did not realize this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Google have a list containing the MAC addresses and all the towers on a determined location. He can collect that data not only by the street view car, but from Android phones as well.

It's easy (for Google) to know the GPS coordinates of every cellphone tower on a city (or country), so correlating it with the data your phone sends is enough to get a very good idea of where you are.

Google already have a database (more or less) like this:

```
coordinates:tower coverage:MAC address
```

So, if you locate one MAC address on the list, you have the coordinates and the cell towers close to it.

Later, even if you have the cell phone disabled, your phone can connect using wifi, pass the MAC of the access point to Google, Google searchs its huge database, finds the MAC, and gets your coordinates.

Comment: Can you clarify how cell towers have anything to do with this? I am asking in the particular case where cell tower connections are disabled and not used.

Comment: So does it mean that a phone needs to be able to **connect** to the wifi network AND have internet access in order for this to work?

Comment: Yes. Unless the phone already did that hours (or days) before, and already knows where it is...

Comment: What are your sources?